# How can I properly define a value and call it with .retrieve in Brownie?

Tags: python, error, brownie, cli

```
transaction = simple_storage.store(15, {"from": account})
transaction.wait(1)
updated_store_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
print(updated_stored_value)
```

This is the code that I am using in this situation. The updated_store_value = 15. When I try to retrieve this integer, and print it I get the error `name updated_store_value is not defined` The way that I am currently doing it makes sense, but I assume that an update in Brownie changed this in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store the result of `retrieve()`function in **updated_store_value** but print **updated_stored_value**. These are two different variables which causes an error.

Comment: Lol, well new question, Do you know if there is an extension on Visual Studio Code that will check the naming of variables and functions because I have run into so many problems that is just because I typed in the name of my variable/function in wrong.